# $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} \cong \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2 = 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> True or false: $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} \cong \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2 = 1\}$

This is a question from my test. When my teacher explained the answer, he did something amazing. I quote what he said:

*Indeed, they are homeomorphic to each other. Imagine a $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane with a hole in the middle. We enlarge the hole so that it becomes a circle with radius $1$. Now, imagine that we put our fingers over the circumference of the hole and then pull up the whole plane. We now get an infinitely long cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^3$.*

Can anyone explain to me that why the above argument is valid? Can we have a more formal proof for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The heuristic visual is to give you an idea how to construct the formal proof. The idea is that for each $r>0,$ we associate $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:x^2+y^2=r^2\}$ to a circular cross-section of the cylinder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can construct a homeomorphism in the two stages he describes.

First $\ \ \ \ \  \ \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(r,\theta) \ | \ r > 1\} \ \ $ defined by $$(r, \theta) \mapsto (r+1,\theta)$$

Second $\ \  \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(r,\theta) \ | \  r > 1\} \rightarrow \{ (\theta, z) \ | \   z \in \mathbb{R} \} \ \ $ where $$ (r,\theta) \mapsto \left (\theta,  r - \frac{2}{r} \right)$$

Comment: Could you explain your answer here to someone that's eager to know what all of this means? What does the forward-slash "\" mean?

Comment: If $S$ and $T$ are sets, $S \setminus T$ means "$S$ with all elements of $T$ removed from it". Often $T \subseteq S$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $z=re^{it}$ and map $z\mapsto (\cos\ t,\sin\ t,\log\ r)$.

It may be easier to think of the professor's argument as creating a finitely long cylinder with no boundary (I.e. open) and then noting that that is homeomorphic to the infinite cylinder.